# What does "$\=$/;" mean in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I came across a perl program which counts the number of vowels in a string. But I'm not able to infer a single line how it is working. Anyone who can decode this program line by line?

```
$\=$/;map{
    $_=<>;print 0+s/[aeiou]//gi
}1..<>
```

Comment: That is a misuse of `map`, and should be done with an ordinary `for` loop: `print <> =~ tr/aeiouAEIOU//, "\n" for 1 .. <>`. I don't know if that's any easier to understand though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> *What does `$\=$/;` mean in perl?*

Sets `$\` to the value of `$/`.

[`$/`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$/) defines the line ending ending for `readline` (`<>`). It's default is a line feed (U+000A).

[`$\`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$%5C) is appended to the output of each `print`. It's default is the empty string.

So, assuming `$/` hadn't been changed, it sets `$\` to line feed, which makes `print` act like `say`.

> *Anyone who can decode this program line by line?*

1. Globally make `print` act like `say`.
2. Read a line from `ARGV`.
3. For a number of times equal to the number read,

   1. Read a line from `ARGV`.
   2. Use `s/[aeiou]//gi` to count the number of vowels.
   3. Print the result.

In scalar context, `s///g` returns the number of matches/replacements. `0+` forces scalar context.

---

By the way, `tr/aeiouAEIOU//` would be faster than `0+s/[aeiou]//gi`, and no longer. It's also non-destructive.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. One more thing what does it mean `1..<>` at the end of map?

Comment: Read a line from ARGV. Create a list of numbers from 1 to the number read.